# How to use H2 as embedded database in Postgres-compat mode, from jruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jruby, h2

I'd like to launch a jruby/rails app to use Postgres.  But I'd like to use H2 in Postgres compatibility mode when running in development and test.

Its no problem bringing up the app in H2, or in postgresql, but how do I configure to run the postgresql adaptor, using an embedded H2 database?

For example: something like this:

database.yml

```
    development:
    #  adapter: jdbch2
    #  database: db/development/database
      adapter: postgresql
      encoding: unicode
      database: database
    #  driver: org.h2.Driver
      url: jdbc:h2:~/db/development;MODE=PostgreSQL

    test:
    ...
```

Gemfile:

```
...
gem 'activerecord-jdbch2-adapter'
#gem 'jdbc-h2'
gem 'activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter'
...
```

Comment: Don't use a different DBMS for testing/development than you use in production. It will give you a lot of trouble in the long run. Postgres is easy to setup and has a very small footprint. So there is no reason *not* to install it on your development computer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name There are a few advantage to use different databases, for example H2 (in-memory, and to a lesser extend embedded) is much faster than databases in client/server mode (as in this example). Also, there is less of a risk to use very database specific features (which would prevent you to switch to another database, if that is ever needed).

Comment: @drsquidop Could you post the PostgreSQL configuration please?

Comment: @ThomasMueller: Not using DBMS specific features is a bad habit. It simply makes the application equally slow on all platforms. Besides major feature differences (window functions, CTE) there are usually many little things that might behave completely different. And finding that out in production isn't really the right way to do it.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think using DBMS specific features is a bad habit, except where really needed. I know that all databases are a bit different, and because of that it makes sense to also test with the production database (for example in the nightly build). However, during development, it's better to use a fast database (such as H2), because that will speed up development.

Comment: @ThomasMueller: a very simple example: `select * from foo order by bar`. This will produce different results in Postgres and H2 if `bar` contains nulls because of different default behaviour. I could use `NULLS LAST` to control that - but that is already DBMS "specific" as not all DBMS support this. So what do do? Additionally: because of the speed advantage bad SQL (think ORM layers) won't be noticed until the application goes to production (and is run against 10 times the data).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I wrote, I think that nightly builds should use the production database. Nightly builds should also test with more data than unit tests. That way, (performance) problems are detected. But it doesn't make sense to use a slow database, and a lot of data, for unit tests. That would slow down development. As for `NULLS LAST`: I think you should use `NULLS LAST/FIRST`, as this makes it clear for the user. This will work with both PostgreSQL and H2 - there is no other database needed :-)

Comment: @ThomasMueller: and where do you stop with features that are not supported by every DBMS? Do you leave out check constraints because MySQL doesn't support them? Do you skip the usage of deferred constraints because only Oracle and Postgres support them? What about the interval datatype. It's standard SQL but yet H2 does not accept `interval '1' month`. What about unique indexes over nullable columns. The behaviour isn't consistent acrross DBMS either. The list is endless and you can't possibly test every aspect of each DBMS in the nightly builds.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think most of the application logic should be in the (Java) code, because that makes testing and porting easier. That doesn't mean an ORM needs to be used. As for check constraints, I would use them, but also have them in the Java code (so you could still port your application to MySQL - the DBMS constraints are just added security). I would try to avoid deferred constraints, unique indexes over nullable columns. But the nightly build should be all automated tests you have, and therefore should be able to test all aspects of your application that you care about.

Comment: Thomas,  there is no postgresql configuration to post, because the goal is for the postgres adaptor to point to the in memory h2 database.

Comment: At least if you insist on using a different db for development than in production **at least test** on the same db you would run on production.  Otherwise, you are asking for big headaches.....